# How to show a loading image while a drop down list renders (not while it loads the data, but while it renders)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu, autocomplete

I'm using jquery's autocomplete combobox and have a long list of data (around 1,000 items).  The data loads fine from the server, but when I try to expand the drop down list, it takes a few seconds for it to be rendered on the screen.  Is there a way to catch the original click event on the drop down and show a loading image until the list of options renders?  I tried a few different ways but each time the javascript doesn't execute until after the list of options renders.

Comment: Not sure, but you may do this: insert the load image into a hidden div, when you click on the dropdown show the load image and use $('#yourlist').ready(function(){ }); (http://api.jquery.com/ready/) to HIDE the load image (once yourlist is ready). Not sure if it works, though. Try to give it a shot!

Answer (score 0):

if there is some animation, you can use jQuery .is(':animated') to show loading bar until it will expand.